Bing Ads SOAP request yeilds Error: read ECONNRESET using NodeJS strong-soap
I'm using strong-soap to make requests to the Microsoft Bing Ads API (specifically this endpoint).
Here's my code:
const wsdlURI = "https://clientcenter.api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/CustomerManagement/v13/CustomerManagementService.svc?singleWsdl";

const options = {
    envelopeKey: 's',
};

soap.createClient(wsdlURI, {
    ...options
}, (err: any, client: any) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }

    client.addSoapHeader(`<h:AuthenticationToken i:nil="false">${access_token}</h:AuthenticationToken>`)
    client.addSoapHeader(`<h:DeveloperToken i:nil="false">${process.env.MICROSOFT_ADS_DEVELOPER_TOKEN}</h:DeveloperToken>`)
    client.GetUser(null, (err: any, res: any, env: any, soapHeader: any) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        console.log("Res:", res)
        console.log("Env:", env)
    }, null)
})

The client gets created successfully, but when I call client.GetUser(), the following error is thrown:
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: -54,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

It's worth noting that if I remove the soap headers (AuthenticationToken & DeveloperToken), the socket does not hang up, and returns:
Authentication failed. Either supplied credentials are invalid or the account is inactive
strong-soap generates the following XML for the request:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:AuthenticationToken i:nil="false">...</h:AuthenticationToken>
    <h:DeveloperToken i:nil="false">...</h:DeveloperToken>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body/>
</s:Envelope>

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Server requires OAUTH2 authentication which is a two step HTTP authentication.  Step 1 is to request a Token/Cookie.  Set 2 is to make a query to server using the Token.  You are only doing one step.  Where are you getting the AuthenticationToken?

We get the authentication token using the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint. The process is not outlined above, but the token we get back is defiantly valid.

Your error is due to the server closing the connection abruptly.  See if following helps : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msadvs/forum/all/updated-2323-unresolved-bing-ads-account/e9cde0d9-c6a1-4811-9929-b76d6b0a2ff3

Thanks for your comment. The account is defiantly active and accessible.

The connection is closing.  Why???
